# Failed to write and apply groupBy spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have got my spark dataframe with following code

```
scala> val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
scala> import sqlContext.implicits._

scala> case class Wiki(project: String, title: String, count: Int, byte_size: String)

scala> val data = sc.textFile("s3n://+++/").map(_.split(" ")).map(p => Wiki(p(0), p(1), p(2).trim.toInt, p(3)))

scala> val df = data.toDF()
```

and try to write to output file:

```
scala> df.write.parquet("df.parquet")
```

or aggregate data with

```
scala> df.filter("project = 'en'").select("title","count").groupBy("title").sum().collect()
```

failed with similar error looks like the following :

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 855.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 855, ip-172-31-10-195.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:251)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at $line24.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:28)
at $line24.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:28)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:242)
... 8 more
```

my dataframe schema is something like the following

```
root
----
-- project: String (true)
-- title: String (true)
-- count: Int (false)
-- byte_size: String (true)
```

How can I interpret this error ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: Is your hadoop cluster working correctly?

Comment: @Reactormonk I think so. I have lauched a spark cluster on AWS EMR. everything seems to be ok. I work interactively in spark-shell

Comment: Could you add your Dataframe schema? Here you have 2 different types of errors!

Comment: @eliasah updated. That is not the exact printSchema output. I have already terminated the cluster, but should be correct in meaning

Comment: What are you actually filter on? Doesn't make any sense!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your split always return array of 4 records. Maybe you have some malformed entries or you split them by a wrong character.

Try to filter with:

```
 val data = sc.textFile("s3n://+++/").map(_.split(" ")).filter(_.size ==4 )map(p => Wiki(p(0), p(1), p(2).trim.toInt, p(3)))
```

And see if the error continues. ArrayIndexOutOfBonds after splitting usually means that some of the records were parsed incorrectly. In your case, the number 2 may mean that `p(2)` could not be set which means that one of the records has only 2 values - `p(0)` and `p(1)`